# The Multiresolution modifier doesn't work as expected

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

So when I'm sculpting with the multi-resolution modifier, the changes I make change when I'm scrolling through to look at it from a better perspective (the middle mouse button and rotating it).  The tutorial I was following didn't have such a case. Is that expected?

Comment: are you talking about the Multiresolution modifier?

Comment: Oh yes! I will change the name in the question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Fast Navigate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/options.html#options) option.

> **Fast Navigate**
>   For multiresolution models, shows low resolution while navigating in the viewport.

It is a viewport optimization, which is useful if your high poly model is slowing down Blender. To disable it, go to the **Tool Options** in sculpt mode, then navigate to the **Options** section and **disable *Fast Navigate***.

[image: fast navigate]